# AlarmManager firing immediately after app closed

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I have an AlarmManager in a PreferenceFragment that kicks off an alarm once a day as planned. Unfortunately it also starts an alarm immediately every time the app is closed. This happens after toggling the relevant preference but it also happens if I open the app on the main activity and then close it again such that this preferencefragment and associated activity were never started.

I can see the previously started service is still running in the background so my best guess is that upon stopping the app the Alarm is recreated causing the immediate alarm, and that I should probably use `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` but I can't seem to get this to work.

I also dont understand why any of this is a problem in the first place. Surely the use of `AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY` should mean that even if the alarm was being recreated then it should not fire for at least a day?

Here is the code in PreferenceFragment:

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    if (key.equals(KEY_PREF_NOTIFICATION)) {

        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), AlarmReciever.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, alarmIntent, 0);

        if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("notification_checkbox", true)) {

            AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

            // turns the boot reciever on
            ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(getActivity(), BootReceiver.class);
            PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();

            pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

            Log.e(TAG, "preference changed");

        } else {
            AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            manager.cancel(pendingIntent);

            // turns the boot reciever off
            ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(getActivity(), BootReceiver.class);
            PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();

            pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

            Log.e(TAG, "preference unchanged");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I was using `START_STICKY`  in the service rather than `START_NOT_STICKY` which meant that the service and not the pending intent was being restarted on every app closure.